# java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input Spring MVC Jackson Processor

Tags: java, json, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and JSP to send JSON to Spring MVC Controller. Actually, my JSON works for 1 method but does not work for another and I don't understand why. The code is below:

JSP - index.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {  
$('#myForm').submit(function() { 
    var form = $( this ), 
        url = form.attr('action'), 
        userId = form.find('input[name="userId"]').val(),
        dat = JSON.stringify({ "userId" : userId }); 

    $.ajax({ 
        url : url, 
        type : "POST", 
        traditional : true, 
        contentType : "application/json", 
        dataType : "json", 
        data : dat, 
        success : function (response) { 
            alert('success ' + response); 
        }, 
        error : function (response) { 
            alert('error ' + response); 
        }, 
    }); 

    return false; 
   }); 
 }); 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {  
$('#emailForm').submit(function() { 
    var form = $( this ), 
        url = form.attr('action'), 
        from = form.find('input[name="from"]').val(),
        to = form.find('input[name="to"]').val(),
        body = form.find('input[name="body"]').val(),
        subject = form.find('input[name="subject"]').val(),
        fileName = form.find('input[name="fileName"]').val(),
        location = form.find('input[name="location"]').val(),
        dat = JSON.stringify({ "from" : from,"to" : to,"body" : body,"subject" : subject,"fileName" : fileName,"location" : location }); 

    $.ajax({ 
        url : url, 
        type : "GET", 
        traditional : true, 
        contentType : "application/json", 
        dataType : "json", 
        data : dat, 
        success : function (response) { 
            alert('success ' + response); 
        }, 
        error : function (response) { 
            alert('error ' + response); 
        }, 
    }); 

    return false; 
   }); 
}); 
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<h2>Application</h2>
<form id="myForm" action="/application/history/save" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="userId" value="JUnit">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<form id="emailForm" action="/application/emailService/sendEmail" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="from" value="name@localhost.com">
    <input type="text" name="to" value="user@localhost.com">
    <input type="text" name="body" value="JUnit E-mail">
    <input type="text" name="subject" value="Email">
    <input type="text" name="fileName" value="attachment">
    <input type="text" name="location" value="location">
    <input type="submit" value="Send Email">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The 1st form works correctly and is deserilized in Spring MVC. A sample of that code is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/history/*")
public class HistoryController {

@RequestMapping(value = "save", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
public @ResponseBody UserResponse save(@RequestBody User user) throws Exception {
    UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
    return userResponse;
}
```

For the 2nd form I am getting exceptions:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/emailService/*")
public class EmailController {

@RequestMapping(value = "sendEmail", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = {"content-type=application/json"})
public void sendEmail(@RequestBody Email email) {
    System.out.println("Email Body:" + " " + email.getBody());
    System.out.println("Email To: " + " " + email.getTo());
}
}
```

Below is the stack trace:

```
 java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:2022)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:1974)
org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1331)
org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:135)
org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:154)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.readWithMessageConverters(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:633)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveRequestBody(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:597)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.resolveHandlerArguments(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:346)
org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:171)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I have tried using the POST too, but still the same problem. I need to use JSP to send JSON data to the Spring MVC Controller.

I am not sure where the problem is.

beans.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.web"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:annotation-config/>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT

```
public class Email implements Serializable {

private String from;
private String to;
private String body;
private String subject;
private String fileName;
private String location;

public Email() {

}

// Getters and setters
}
```

JSON sent is in form2 which is #emailForm.

Comment: How does your `Email` class look like and what JSON is sent to that controller? Please edit your question and add these two details.

Comment: Please see changes above. JSON can be seen in emailForm form tag.

Comment: Just so you know, you don't need to stringify your object literal. jQuery will accept an object-literal just fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the data is reaching the controller? Take a look at your net tab. This exception can happen if you're sending an empty POST or GET.

Comment: yes, I am sure the data is reaching the controller for the application/save method. I tried with POST for the emailService and the data reaches the server. However, the problem is with GET only. Any ideas?

Comment: However, when GET is sent it shows Http 500 Internal Server error.

Comment: can someone please give this a try on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, but I used curl to verify the server side function.

The initial data section in my curl command is

`-d "{'id':'123456', 'name':'QWERT'}"`

After I changed the command to

`-d '{"id":"123456", "name":"QWERT"}'`

then it worked.

Hope this gives some hints.

Comment: My cause was extra arguments after request body argument in the method.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if you have set "content-length" header.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I tried to use POST method with path parameter, but I forgot to put `'@PathParam("id") Integer id'`, I just had `'Integer id '` in parameters.